# Cannot clone remote repository with SSH

Tags: git, ssh

I'm new to using Git and I am trying to understand why I cannot clone a remote repository using SSH. When I try to, it states that the System Cannot find the path specified.

```html
git clone -u /mingw64/bin/git-upload-pack ssh://administrator@10.20.32.7/Git/quizinator
```

However, I can clone the repository just fine using the following command.

```html
git clone -u /mingw64/bin/git-upload-pack file:////10.20.32.7/Git/quizinator
```

I've tried creating the a repo under the program files and even under the user account and I always get the same results. I just do not understand why one method works and the other does not.

Comment: It appears that the home directory for the administrator user on 10.20.32.7 does not have a Git/quizzinator folder.

Comment: I thought that was the problem but I added it to the directory and the problem still occurred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a `file://` URL, the `-u` argument to [`git clone`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-clone.html) is *ignored*:

> `--upload-pack <upload-pack>`, `-u <upload-pack>`
>          When given, ***and the repository to clone from is accessed via ssh,***
>    this specifies a non-default path for the command run on the other
>    end.

(emphasis mine).  The `file://` URL makes your Git do all the work itself (your Git acts as both sender and receiver), so the `file://` clone is quite unrelated to anything SSH-ish.

Given the URL, you might try:

```
ssh administrator@10.20.32.7 ls -l /mingw64/bin/git-upload-pack
```

to see what the other machine thinks about `/mingw64/bin/git-upload-pack` (I'm asssuming `ls -l` will work due to mingw64; I don't "do" Windows though).  If that works, you can then try:

```
ssh administrator@10.20.32.7 ls -ld Git/quizinator
```

to see what it thinks of that.

Comment: After I was able to connect it didn't like the -ls and was stating that it was not recognized as an internal command, once I removed and tried it again it then said my permission was denied, could be a configuration problem on my server. I'm going to just stick with using the file:// method. It works it's just and we should be fine since permissions are set on the share. Thanks for the help.